# How can I attach wooden shelf ledgers to concrete foundation walls?

Tags: concrete, fastener

I am installing some garage shelves for my friend. She wants it strong so she can climb up them, and load it with heavy boxes. It’s no problem for me except that these walls, which will go floor to garage door open height, have concrete foundation walls til about half way up (52”). My design for shelves is like most with ledger boards going horizontal. But how will I attach my ledger boards to the concrete retaining wall? I see lots of information online for brick walls, just not concrete.

It’s a newer house probably built in 2015 so the concrete should be good quality. I do have access to a hammer drill as well. I will be using lag bolts on the section that’s in the wood studs, just wondering about the bottom concrete half.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of concrete anchors available. Have you looked into them? Which you choose partly depends on the tools you have available. However, I'd consider freestanding shelves attached to the framing above.

Since your plan is to use lag screws already, why not use anchors designed to accommodate them? This way you can use the same screws throughout.

Lag Shield

[image]

Expanding Anchor

[image]

Concrete Screws

[image]

Comment: Hi , yes I have been looking up all the different anchors and can’t find a clear answer on what is better to use. Most videos use concrete cinder blocks which is not what I have. I have never used a lag shield so I am unsure if it’s actually that amazing? Just wondering if somebody had used one and enjoyed it. 2 outta 3 shelves are on the concrete wall so I definitely wanna anchor them. Cheers.

Comment: The first two products will hang a truck. Concrete screws are a little more fussy as they can snap off fairly easily and sometimes they don't grab before the threads strip out the concrete. They are a good option if you're willing to do a little trial and error and prefer a lighter option with a smaller hole.